# Pandas: Remove all characters before a specific character (last specific character) in a dataframe column that specific character is repeated 4 times

Tags: python, pandas, split

Here is a dataframe constructed with a header column "ParentPath"

```
data = {'ParentPath': ['Hi \ All \ First Name \ Last Name \ A \ 200', 'Hi \ All \ First Name \ Middle Name \ Last Name \ B \ 33', 'Hi \ All \ First Name \ C \ 199', 'Hi \ All \ First Name \ D \ 333', 'Hi \ All \ First Name \ E \ 12', 'Hi \ All \ F \ 88']}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
     ParentPath        
0   Hi \ All \ First Name \ Last Name \ A \ 200        
1   Hi \ All \ First Name \ Middle Name \ Last Name \ B \ 33        
2   Hi \ All \ First Name \ C \ 199        
3   Hi \ All \ First Name \ D \ 333        
4   Hi \ All \ First Name \ E \ 12        
5   Hi \ All \ F \ 88
```

Output needed as shown below after removing all characters after the last " \ " keep in mind there is a space after and before each "backslash"

```
    ParentPath        
0   Hi \ All \ First Name \ Last Name \ A        
1   Hi \ All \ First Name \ Middle Name \ Last Name \ B        
2   Hi \ All \ First Name \ C        
3   Hi \ All \ First Name \ D        
4   Hi \ All \ First Name \ E        
5   Hi \ All \ F
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting and then joining:

```
df['ParentPath'] = df['ParentPath'].str.split(' \\\\ ').str[:-1].str.join(' \\ ')
```

Output:

```
                                          ParentPath
0                Hi \ All \ First Name \ Last Name \ A
1  Hi \ All \ First Name \ Middle Name \ Last Name \ B
2                            Hi \ All \ First Name \ C
3                            Hi \ All \ First Name \ D
4                            Hi \ All \ First Name \ E
5                                         Hi \ All \ F
```